# Plot more curves in one graph

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to plot more curves in one window , I want to see superposing those curves.. Concretely plot **RHO_start** for 3 curves in one window. I don´t know how to write in my code. Here is it:

```
clear,clc,close all

abc='abc'; cal=18/230;

Results=[]; 

data=[];
for i=1:3
    im=imread(['vz_' num2str(j) abc(i) '.jpg']);
    im=imresize(im,0.5);
    %figure,imshow(im)
    I=rgb2gray(im);
    %figure,imshow(I);
    J=imadjust(I);
    %figure,imshow(J);
    T=graythresh (J);
    BW=im2bw(J,T);
    %figure,imshow(BW);
    BWI=1-BW;
    %figure,imshow(BWI);
    B=imclearborder(BWI);
    O=bwareaopen(B,40000);
    H=imfill(O,'holes');
    L=bwlabel(H);
    S=regionprops(L,'Area','Perimeter');
    SE=[0 1 0;1 1 1;0 1 0];
    %figure,imshow(H);
    D=imdilate(H,SE);
    E=edge(D,'canny');
    %imshow(E);
    bound=bwboundaries(E);
    %figure,imshow(E);hold on;
    for k=1
        b=bound{k};
        %plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'r','LineWidth',1.5);
    end
    for x=1:numel(S)
        %plot(S(x).Centroid(1),S(x).Centroid(2),'ro');
    end
    xx=b(:,2);
    yy=b(:,1);
    %figure,plot(xx,yy);axis equal;
    XX=xx-mean(xx);
    YY=yy-mean(yy);
    THETA=XX;
    RHO=YY;
    %figure,plot(XX,YY);axis equal;
    [THETA,RHO]=cart2pol(XX,YY);
    %figure,polar(THETA,RHO);
    %figure,plot(THETA);
    %figure,plot(RHO);
    RHO_smooth=smooth(RHO,30);
    [Mc,Xc]=min(RHO_smooth);
    *RHO_start* =[RHO_smooth(Xc:size(RHO_smooth));RHO_smooth(1:Xc)];
    tc=1:length(RHO_start);
    [~,locsc]=findpeaks(RHO_start,'MinPeakHeight',160,'MinPeakDistance',50);
    figure;hold on;
    plot(tc,RHO_start);
    plot(locsc,RHO_start(locsc),'rv','MarkerFaceColor','r');
    grid on;
    title('Number of peaks');
    xlabel('angle');
    ylabel('radius');
    data=[data; i (S.Area)*cal^2 (S.Perimeter)*cal];
end
data
As=mean(data(:,2));
Results=[Results; j As];
end
```

Comment: Check out my answer. Also note that you should not use `i` as a variable name since it is uses for complex (imaginary) numbers. Your code will work for now, but something else might break later on when you still have `i` in your workspace and you run a different script.

Answer (score 3):

To plot more things in the same axes use [`hold on`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?refresh=true) :

```
figure;
hold on;
plot(1:10,1:10);
plot(1:5,:2:6);
```

to plot more than one axes in each plot use [`subplot`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

```
figure;
subplot(121)
plot(1:10,1:10);
subplot(122)
hold on
plot(1:10,1:10);
plot(1:5,:2:6);
```

Answer (score 2):

example:
Assuming you want to plot different data y1 and y2 against the same vector x, you can do

```
figure
plot(x,y1);
hold on;
plot(x,y2);
legend('Data1', 'Data2')
```

`figure` creates a new window. You only want to call this once! Otherwise if you take your case as an example 3 windows will pop up, each with one plot.

`hold on` tells matlab to not overwrite the old plot with the new one. Otherwise only the latest plot would be visible.

And here's an example with a loop:

```
figure   % Create one figure to draw in
hold on;
for iter=1:10      % In matlab you should never use 'i' as a variable name
  plot(x,y{iter})  % Assuming that y is now a cell containing the individual vectors
end
```

EDIT: Adding colors to your plots

You probably already know the "normal" way of specifying the color via a keyword:

```
plot(x,y,'color', 'green')
```

But you can easily create your own colors using the **RGB** (Red Green Blue) scheme. RGB Colors are defined by three values, each value describing the intensity of the corresponding color. You can mix a lot of colors only from these three (everything your monitor is displaying now is very likely defined in RGB). Usually **RGB** is defined by **3 bits** and a bit has **256** values. Therefore your values can take on values **between 0 and 255**. 
However, **Matlab** uses RGB values in the **range between 0 and 1**. So, if you want to specify the color **black** you have to use `[0 0 0]` and for **white** `[1 1 1]`.

RGB Colors can be found with google, just type in **"RGB Table"** in the image search and there you should find what you need. Since these tables often specify the colors in the **0-255** range, you can use these values and simply divide your vector by 255.

Let me show you: Let's first define some colors we can use later on

```
color_red = [255 0 0]/255;
color_green = [0 255 0]/255;
color_blue = [0 0 255]/255;
color_orange = [255 102 0]/255;
color_pink = [204, 0, 102]/255;
```

Now our colors can simply be used like the ones integrated in matlab

```
plot(x,y,'color', color_pink);     
plot(x,y,'color', [0.8, 0, 0.4]);  % Same as above
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for advices and comments! Do you know, how can I create all these curves in different colors? I have 10 curves but not enough colors..I use: colorstring='rgbcmyk'; thats just 7 colors..